# How to commit execute procedure in firebird from asterisk?

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, asterisk

I have execute procedure in Firebird and calling from asterisk.
The transaction not commited after complete procedure, but after asterisk$> reload transaction commited.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know asterisk, but you probably need to explicitly commit.

Answer (score 0):

Data manipulation language statements are not committed automatically. 
You must issue a "commit" statement to commit any DML changes to the database.

If after reload you've seen the execution results commited, be sure that when going down for reload asterisk transaction handler has issued the commit statement.

Comment: You can use func_odbc in asterisk and put commit in that function.